# Method not allowed HTTPS spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, https

how it's going?

I have a `RestApi` built in Spring. There are some functional endpoints using `GET` and `POST` Methods. I tried add a **https** configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector getHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8081);
    return connector;
  }
}
```

Before I had like `http://localhost:8080/api/candidates [GET]` and after added this class, the url was redirecting to **https**, what is normal, so now I am redirecting to `https://localhost:8081/api/candidates`.

After that I have done this, when I try access the endpoint without `HTTPS` `http://localhost:8080/api/candidates` using `GET` I can retrieve all information, but when I try using `POST` to send some data I receive
`Method not allowed` but `GET` is working yet. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: I had this issue with using springsecurity. Post was only allowed if I disabled csrf in the security settings.  Maybe it also the problem in your case.

Comment: I have in my configure method something like this  
                 http.requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests().....
So basically it is already disabled

Comment: Did you check that none of your post parameters is null?

Comment: Can you post your controller code too?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? Should a POST be redirected too to https?

Answer (score 2):

I found this post, and it was exaclty what I was looking for. If you want see please check [Spring Boot: redirect from HTTP to HTTPS results in 405 error for PUT method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629911/spring-boot-redirect-from-http-to-https-results-in-405-error-for-put-method)

> A redirect is specifically to inform the client (e.g. web browser) to
> do a GET request using a given URL, so the result of a redirect cannot
> be a PUT, POST, DELETE, or any other HTTP method.
>
> In this context, the main purpose of redirecting to HTTPS is to secure
> the connection from snooping, i.e. ensure that no one can see
> confidential information. This works well for a GET, since you haven't
> sent confidential information yet1, assuming it is the response that
> contains confidential information.
>
> Redirecting a PUT or a POST to HTTPS is meaningless, since you already
> sent the payload (the confidential data) over an unsecure connection.
>
> Your client needs to be told to use HTTPS before it sends the data,
> i.e. when it builds the PUT / POST request, it needs to be given an
> HTTPS URL.
>
> Fix the client code, e.g. the JavaScript code that generates the HTTP
> PUT, so it uses HTTPS. Redirecting is too late, and entirely wrong.
>
> It is actually a good thing that redirect of PUT failed, because it
> forces you to correctly secure your web application. If it hadn't
> failed, you'd mistakenly have thought that you web application was
> secured by the redirect, when in fact it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting GET requests is not the same as redirecting POST requests. Please read [this](https://www.itprotoday.com/server-virtualization/redirecting-post-requests). They state following:

> Redirecting GET requests, which contain no data other then a query string, is a simple process. However, POST requests are more difficult to redirect because a browser responding to a 302 or 301 redirection converts an initial POST request to a GET request—a process that loses the original POST request data.